# What does "shuffle the comparisons into one dataset" mean?

Tags: reward-functions, instruct-gpt

I couldn't understand the wording here.

[image: Training for the comparisons]

What does "shuffle the comparisons into one dataset" mean?

How does the method they use don't have $K \choose 2$ forward passes for K completions? Do they update $K \choose 2$ in an epoch for K completions or what?

Comment: Please, provide the link to the actual paper, not just the screenshot.